# If statement is blank then display otherwise display value XSL CODE

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The following code uses if statement to read if value is empty if so then display value otherwise display other value, however I am still receiving a blank value for everything.

```
<PayeeID xtt:fixedLength="12">
        <xsl:choose>

          <!-- When Payer Bank == Payee Bank -->
          <xsl:when test="$isTransfer = false()">

            <xsl:if
            test="CalculatedFieldData/Field_Value[@name='Nat_ID']=''">
              <xsl:value-of
                select="normalize-space(Payment_Detail/Receive_Party_And_Bank_Data/wpc:PAY_Taxid)"/>
            </xsl:if>

          </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of
                            select="normalize-space(translate(CalculatedFieldData/Field_Value[@name='Nat_ID'],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ()-_',''))"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </PayeeID>
```

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, incl. input and expected output - see: [mcve]. -- Also, select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: There is no input, its reading data and creating an ouput. if the field its reading from is blank then display select=" " otherwise select=" " other field data.

Comment: "*There is no input, its reading data*" I think you have a contradiction there.

Comment: add your input and expected XML

Comment: You have two separate conditions; `$isTransfer = false()` and `CalculatedFieldData/Field_Value[@name='Nat_ID']=''`, which gives a total of 4 possible outcomes. However you are only accounting for two outcomes. You haven't catered for `$isTransfer = true()` and `FieldValue != ''`, or when `$isTransfer = false()` and `Field_Value=''`